# Converting CSV rows string into array

Tags: php, csv

I am using an API that returns a CSV string as the following:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close 2014-06-13,3.10,3.30,3.10,3.30,6638300,3.30
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to convert this CSV string to an associative array? I am familiar with working with a CSV file, but not sure what to do with a CSV file string response. I am trying to avoid writing the response to a file, just so I can read it back.

Note, writing this response to a CSV file would result in two rows and seven columns.

Comment: You could use [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), but you'd need to figure out where the line breaks are. What's the line terminator?

Comment: check php's [`explode()`](http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

Comment: @vitro, explode doesn't create **associative** arrays.

Comment: @Mike, the terminator is `\r\n`

Comment: @AnchovyLegend it does not but with a little bit of work you can loop the lines of csv and make the structure you want

Comment: if the terminator is `\r\n`, explode them thru that, get the first element, which is the headers, then loop and create new arrays using those headers as keys

Comment: You get one header line and one line of data or multiple lines of data?

Comment: My mistake, the terminator is not `\r\n`, now that I am trying it, IDK what the terminator is. Both `"\r\n"` AND `"\n"` arent working :/

Comment: @AbraCadaver, most of the time just headers + one line of data.

Comment: Have you double-checked the API documentation? The terminator should be specified. You could try analyzing the string char-by-char via ord() function [which returns the ASCII char value].

Answer (score 1):

If the line terminator is `\r\n`, then first you need to explode them thru that. Then you can proces from there. Consider this example:

```
$data = explode("\r\n", $csv_string);
// get the headers first
$headers = array_map('trim', explode(',', array_shift($data)));
$new_data = array();
// get the values and use array combine to use the headers as keys for associative array
foreach($data as $values) {
    $pieces = explode(',', $values);
    // i just assigned it in an array, since we dont know how many lines of data you will receive
    $new_data[] = array_combine($headers, $pieces);
}
```

`$new_data` should yield something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2014-06-13
            [Open] => 3.10
            [High] => 3.30
            [Low] => 3.10
            [Close] => 3.30
            [Volume] => 6638300
            [Adj Close] => 3.30
        )

)
```

Or just the usual way of handling csv strings. Use `str_getcsv()`.

```
$data = str_getcsv($csv_string, "\r\n");
$headers = explode(',', array_shift($data));
$data = array_combine($headers, explode(',',reset($data)));
```

Comment: @JakeGould, `str_getcsv()` doesn't work on this input. Try it. The 7th cell is clumped with 8th, it doesn't detect the line break.

Comment: @kevinabelita, thanks Kevin. Unfortunately, this did not work. I am getting this warning and the array is not lined properly: `Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in C:\mypath\test.php on line 67`

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) is your friend and is an easy method to convert a CSV string into an array. This function will return an array of results. If you'd like to make it an associative array, use [array_combine()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Honestly, though -- str_getcsv() may be overkill. Consider this method using [explode()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
// so given this string returned by the API
$api_s = "Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close\r\n2014-06-13,3.10,3.30,3.10,3.30,6638300,3.30";

// split on carriage return & line feed into two strings
$api_r = explode("\r\n", $api_s);

// split keys and values by comma
$keys = explode(',', $api_r[0]);
$vals = explode(',', $api_r[1]);

// construct associative array
$my_assoc_r = array_combine($keys, $vals);
```